# CSS3 PIE and jQuery Sparkle

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder, css3pie

I'm using CSS3 PIE to add support for rounded corners and shadows to IE, and jQuery Sparkle to add support for the HTML5 placeholder attribute. Whenever I apply PIE to any containing element of a form field that has the placeholder attribute, the placeholder text disappears.

After further testing, the behavior isn't consistent - if I sit there and keep refreshing the page, once in a while the placeholder text WILL appear even with PIE applied to one of its containing elements. This leads me to believe it has something to do with the order in which PIE/Sparkle are loaded. My guess is that if PIE loads first then Sparkle can add the placeholders after the fact, but if Sparkle loads first then PIE wipes them out when it redraws the containing element? Just a theory.

Anyway, any help on this would be much appreciated as if I can't use both together, I'll either have to redo my form with labels outside the fields or redo my page design with images instead of CSS3 effects. I'd prefer neither :-)

Comment: Can you make an example page? This sounds like a bug in CSS PIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [pure JS version](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/) of PIE as opposed to the htc? its [shotgun debugging](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/shotgun-debugging.html), but it might work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, that never even occurred to me.